# my language has been change but i have not any result

Tags: php, yii, translation

i am beginner in yii framwork
i want to change language in my project  i tried but it was ineffective
i explain steps then u help me and tell my wrong
i did:

add 'sourceLanguage'=>'en_us', and  'language'=>'fa-ir' in \protected\config\main.php  copy fa-ir folder fromyii\framework\messages 
copy to myprojectname\protected\messages
add to myprojectname\protected\views\site below code

```
$lang = Yii::app()->language;
echo "my lang is:::::".$lang;
Yii::t('zii','Delete');
Yii::t('yii','Get a new code');
```

**my language has been change but i have not any result**

i think i must to clean catch files in directory
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can follow [this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/6137-example-of-changing-language/) for guid through setting up your language support.
have you done setting up your message folder?

[Change language in YII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325996/change-language-in-yii)

[this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/26/setting-and-maintaining-the-language-in-application-i18n/) is good for maintaining a language support

Comment: ohh please reply well!!! i did all configure i set  'sourceLanguage'=>'en_us', and 'language'=>'fa-ir' in \protected\config\main.php ,i can search , I  read this page

Comment: how did you setup your /protected/messages ?