# How to setup yii for mulitple language with different layout?

Tags: yii

I need

Home
 About Us
 Contact Us

Page in three language with 3 different layout.

how can i do it in yii framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller action

```
 $this->layout='//layouts/layout_name';
```

In your config file

```
   return array(
   ...
   'sourceLanguage' => 'fr',
  'language'=>'en',
  ...
  'params' => array(
           ...
           'languages'=>array('en_us'=>'English', 'fr'=>'French', 'fa_ir'=>'?????'),
           ....
           ), 
 );
```

To change it from anywhere,

```
 Yii::app()->language = Yii::app()->params->languages['fa_ir'];
```

See this[Reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325996/change-language-in-yii)

Comment: but how can i  set language?

Answer (score 0):

Yi framework`s own definitive guide is a nice way to start that. 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.i18n

Also you can follow this wiki article.
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/26/setting-and-maintaining-the-language-in-application-i18n/